# iconbitmap does not work with ico file, gives "not defined" error

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.10

I can not set an icon (.ico file)

```
root.iconbitmap("stuff/icon.ico")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kekx/Dokumente/VS/Shorty/shorty.py", line 213, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap("stuff/icon.ico")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2109, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "stuff/icon.ico" not defined
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
.
+-- shorty.py
+-- stuff
    +-- icon.ico
    +-- ...
```

When I start the script via terminal the same error occurs (of course I changed into the directory of the script)

Does anyone know what this can be?

I have also already tried:

```
root.iconbitmap(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/stuff/icon.ico")
```

Comment: Where is `"shorty.py"` located in your file structure? It should be in the same folder as the folder where `run.py` is located

Comment: Oh sry my mistake, shorty.py and run.py are the same file

Comment: Ok can you now try printing the `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and see what it prints? (It should print this `/home/kekx/Dokumente/VS/Shorty`)

Comment: Exactly, but also does not work

Comment: It will be much better if you use `Path` from `pathlib`, you can also verify `print(os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/stuff/icon.ico"))` to know if the file exists

Comment: But with the absolute path it didn't work either

Comment: What does the print return

Comment: Well, what you expect: True

Comment: I have tried it with the relative and absolute path

Comment: Aren't you using macOS/linux, I do not think `ico` exists for these, you might need to use `png` with `root.iconphoto`

Comment: Your error stating return tk.call. Does this help? root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/stuff/icon.ico')

Comment: @toyotaSupra You cannot use `ico` inside `iconphoto`

Comment: U'r right @Delrius Euphoria

Comment: @Delrius Euphoria | I'm on Linux, that could be, I'll try iconphoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `iconphoto` instead of `iconbitmap` on Linux/macOS systems, to try:

```
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/img.png')
root.iconphoto(True, icon)
```